# ContentDisposition class throwing inconsistent exception

Tags: c#, parsing, http, webclient, content-disposition

I'm using a WebClient to discover a download file name, using the content-disposition.

Calling `client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"]` returns the following string:

```
attachment; filename="2013122100000030141b0feedd40488fa2b0691fa6ae2a.zip
```

then,

```
fileName = new ContentDisposition(responseHeader).FileName;
```

throws the exception **"The specified content disposition is invalid."**:

```
System.FormatException: The specified content disposition is invalid. ---> System.FormatException: The mail header is malformed.
   at System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadQuotedString(String data, Int32& offset, StringBuilder builder, Boolean doesntRequireQuotes, Boolean permitUnicodeInDisplayName)
   at System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition.ParseValue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition.ParseValue()
   at System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition..ctor(String disposition)
```

I've figured out that the content-disposition string is missing the trailing quotation mark. When the quotation mark (") is placed after .zip, it works.

The server seems to be an IIS 6. Is it a bug in `ContentDisposition` class? I don't want to worry treating that string by removing unwanted quotation marks, but I can't explain "who" is wrong in this case, the server or the class. Any idea?

Update:

According to the [HTTP Content-Disposition specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1):

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a
>   means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user
>   requests that the content is saved to a file. This usage is derived
>   from the definition of Content-Disposition in RFC 1806 [35].
>
> ```
>     content-disposition = "Content-Disposition" ":"
>                           disposition-type *( ";" disposition-parm )
>     disposition-type = "attachment" | disp-extension-token
>     disposition-parm = filename-parm | disp-extension-parm
>     filename-parm = "filename" "=" quoted-string
>     disp-extension-token = token
>     disp-extension-parm = token "=" ( token | quoted-string ) An example is
>
>     Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
> ```

From the referenced RFCs, the quotation mark is not a constraint, so I think ContentDisposition class should be more flexible to accept unquoted strings in filename.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant RFC is http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html. And no, starting with a quote but leaving out the ending quote is incorrect.

Comment: I agree, but why an IIS server would return this way?